# Is android:exported="true" really necessary for an authentication service?

Tags: android, authentication, android-manifest

There are usually two services involved with implementing an Android authenticator - the Authentication service to return an authenticator, and the Sync service which provides a sync adapter. This question is specifically about the Authentication service, although in [most examples](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/AndroidManifest.html) *both* services are given the `android:exported="true"` attribute in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, eg:

```
<service
    android:name=".authenticator.AuthenticationService"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
        android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
</service>
```

Removing the attribute from the Authentication service seems to have no effect (tested Froyo, Gingerbread) - the auth code continues to work just fine - so is the flag actually necessary?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Ok, to answer this myself by reading the docs, the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#exported) for the `exported` attribute says:

> The default value depends on whether the service contains intent
>   filters. The absence of any filters means that it can be invoked only
>   by specifying its exact class name. This implies that the service is
>   intended only for application-internal use (since others would not
>   know the class name). So in this case, the default value is "false".
>   On the other hand, the presence of at least one filter implies that
>   the service is intended for external use, so the default value is
>   "true".

All Authentication services have an intent filter - the docs for [AbstractAccountAuthenticator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html) say:

> In order to be an authenticator one must ... write a service that
>   returns the result of getIBinder() in the service's
>   onBind(android.content.Intent) when invoked with an intent with action
>   ACTION_AUTHENTICATOR_INTENT.

This requires an intent filter, consequently the default value of exported for the service is `true`. So the answer to this question is *"No, the attribute is **not** necessary - because it's true by default"*.

Comment: Since Android 4.2 , The default value of android:exported is now false.

Comment: Could you link to some documentation that shows that? The Android doc linked to above still says: '...On the other hand, the presence of at least one filter implies that the service is intended for external use, so the default value is "true".'

Comment: I do see this documentation: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html - which says 'Content providers are no longer exported by default.' - but that only relates to Content providers, not Services, I think?

Comment: Oh yes you're right. That is false for content providers only.

Comment: For Broadcast Receiver the default value is `true` if there is at least one <intent-filter> specified and `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

While not actually required, this seems to create some confusion. This is why [Google recommends](https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/core-app-quality#core) to

> Always set the `android:exported` attribute explicitly, regardless of whether or not you export any of your application's components.

in their [core app quality guidelines](https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/core-app-quality#core).

Answer (score 0):

The `android:exported` attribute sets whether a component (`activity`, `service`, `broadcast receiver`, etc.) can be launched by components of other applications: If true, any app can access the activity and launch it by its exact class name.